# Populate users having a given role in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two schemas that I've been using to run users and privileges on my basic site.  The site consists of an express.js framework with mongoose over mongodb.  The schemas look similar to this:

```
UserSchema = new Schema({
  Name: { type: String },
  Email: { type: String },
  Roles: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Role' }]
});

RoleSchema = new Schema({
  Name: { type: String }
})
```

I can insert users with or without roles, and I can create roles with no problem.  The issue occurs when I delete a role.  The user will end up maintaining a reference to it and cause problems when trying to search on the user's roles.  What I need to do is something like

```
UserModel.find({ })
  .where('Roles').contains(roleID)
  .exec(function(err, users) { })
```

This should give me only the users that have that role.  Any ideas?

Comment: What is `contains`? `UserModel.find().where('Roles', roleID).exec(function(err, users) {} )`

Comment: Contains was just a way of describing what I wanted.  Turns out it was much easier than I expected it to be.  Thanks.

Comment: My comment had the answer. :)

Comment: I know, but I couldn't mark it as the answer 'cause it's a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a mongodb query has `someArray: someValue` by default it intereprets that as "match any parent document where someArray contains someValue". So this is trivial:

```
UserModel.find({Roles: roleId}, callback);
```

---

Side note: when you ask a question about mongoose and use the word 'populate', that means mongoose's populate feature. In this case it looks like you are asking about a vanilla collection query.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I guess I was making it more difficult than it needed to be.  As for 'populate', I expected that I would need to use the populate function to make this work, which is why I included it.